# calling next(err) multiple time

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling, middleware

first, i am sorry if it's not a good problem as i am very new to node and express js. Now,

what will be the flow of express code while using error middleware and calling next(err) multiple time inside my route handler

```
app.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
  // const err = new Error("An example error");
  console.log("pass 1");
  next("m1"); // First time the error is passed
  console.log("pass 2");
  next("m2"); // Second time the error is passed
});

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  console.log("error middleware called");
  res.json({ message: "error here" });
});
```

i thought i would call error middleware 2 time but it's giving this\

```
pass 1
error middleware called
pass 2
GET / 200 3.668 ms - 24
m2
```

so what would be the flow of the code? Thankyou

Comment: You should only ever call `next(err)` just once per request.  Don't call it multiple times for the same request.  Express will protect against calling the error middleware multiple times for the same request because you're not supposed to call it multiple times.

Comment: so, can you tell me how will express handle it (how only "m2" is printed not "m1") when next(err) called for second time? Also, what will be the difference when passing string to next() (without using try() catch() block) as what i know from documentation is that error obj should passed to next() and next() must reside inside catch block

Comment: If you want to know how Express figures it out, you'll have to either step through this code in the debugger to see how Express does it or study the Express code on Github.  The point is, you aren't supposed to call `next(err)` multiple times.  My guess would be that Express stores the error for a response, but sends it asynchronously so if you set the error multiple times synchronously, the last one set overwrites the prior one and is the one that gets actually sent.  But, that's just a guess.  If you want to know precisely, you will have to study the code to see how it does it.